# Nested ng-repeat to create multiple table with different data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have Json data

```
[{"ID": "01000", "Name" : "Name1", "Age" : 25},
 {"ID": "01001", "Name" : "Name2", "Age" : 30},
 {"ID": "01001", "Name" : "Name3", "Age" : 23}]
```

and  want to show this data in multiple table using ng-repeat. table should look like this

[image: How the tables should look like]

I've created function which locates Distinct ID's into "$scope.ID" variable.

```
    $scope.ID = [];
    $scope.ID.push("1");
    var s = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Report.length; i++){

        if ($scope.ID[s] != $scope.Report[i].Id){
            $scope.ID.push($scope.Report[i].Id);                 
            s++;
        }            
    }
```

Then I'm trying to display data into table in this way

```
    <div class="table" ng-repeat="id in ID" ng-model="query">

    <div class="row header">
      <div class="cell">
        ID
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        NAME
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        AGE
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row"  ng-repeat="r in Report | filter: query track by $index">
      <div class="cell">
        {{r.id}}
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        {{r.name}}
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
       {{r.age}}
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Script returns two table but, each table has the same three value,

[image: What the tables actually look like]

I need that each generated table had own filter value, for this case first table should be filtered by ID: 01000 and second table By ID: 01001.

What should I do for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="row header">
  <div class="cell">
    ID
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    NAME
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    AGE
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row"  ng-repeat="r in Report | filter: {id: id}">
  <div class="cell">
    {{r.id}}
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    {{r.name}}
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   {{r.age}}
  </div>

</div>
```